# Why does this int and string concatenation give this output in C++

Tags: c++

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  cout << i+"passs" << "\n";
}
```

This produces output as follows:

```
passs
asss
sss
ss
s
```

Now my thinking is that we are seeing a pointer manipulation where the counter i gets added to passs char pointer and we are seeing output from "passs" pointer+0,"passs" pointer+1 etc.

Question beckons as to why it does not stop when it reaches null character, coz it prints 5 blank lines.

Next is the `cout << "passs"+i << "\n";` prints the same thing. I thought this should have printed all blank lines from second position as this time the passs pointer should have been probably from last position. On reading what I wrote here, it probably makes sense to see that the output for the 2nd cout would be the way it is.

I wanted to know if I'm thinking correctly and if there is more to this which I've not comprehended?

Comment: As you've realised, it's not a "concatenation". So the question title makes you look more confused than you really are ;-)

Comment: @Steve lol, should have worded properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial reasoning is correct.  You're doing pointer arithmetic here, so the first six lines (the sixth being `\0\n`) of output are good.  But you get into trouble when you walk off the end of the string.  There's nothing in your for-loop to stop the iteration, so your program theoretically could do anything with `"passs"` + 6, 7, 8, and 9.  Let's look into why.

Recall that a string literal has type `const char *`.  At some spot in memory determined by the compiler, you have:

```
| p | a | s | s | s | \0 | * | * | * | * |
```

The `*` symbols represent a no-man's land of indeterminate memory past the end of your string.  As your for-loop runs, it starts at `p` and walks forward.  Since we're addressing a `const char *`, each step will be one byte.  At each step, `cout` tries to print as much as it can until reaches a null character (as you see in the output).  But you're not allowed to try to print anything from no-man's land.  Doing so results in **undefined behavior**.  In your case, that memory contained unprintable characters.

So in summary, you were mostly correct.  `cout` did stop printing when it reached a null.  But the for-loop didn't.

Comment: "you're not allowed to try to print anything from no-man's land. Doing so results in undefined behavior." -- merely *creating the pointer* results in undefined behavior. The motivation for this is that (1) the memory for `"passs"` might just happen to be at the very end of the address space, so that adding 6 to it results in an overflow, and (2) C++ aims to allow ancient and peculiar architectures on which pointer overflow results in a hardware fault (although not unsigned int overflow, that has to wrap around). So, `6 + "passs"` is UB whether you print it or not.

Comment: I thought you were guaranteed to be able to address (but not dereference) one-past-end in order to support standard library algorithms.  So having a pointer to +6 in this case is ok, but +7 through +9 are not.  Anyway, this is a good point, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: sorry, you're right, I should have said 7 instead of 6 in two places in my comment. It means that as you say, the "first" UB in the questioner's loop is dereferencing `6 + "passs"`. the "next" UB is computing `7 + "passs"`.

Answer (score 4):

You're right.

The string literal is interpreted as a pointer to the start of the string. Adding an int to this is a pointer increment.

Once you go past the end, you're into undefined behaviour - it seems fairly harmless on your system, but might end in a coredump on another.

Answer (score 2):

It's because a string literal is treated as pointer (pointer arithmetic): adding an integer to a pointer moves forward the pointer:

```
"passs" + 1 = "asss"
"passs" + 2 = "sss"
"passs" + 3 = "ss"
```

to add a number as a string you should use:

```
cout << i << "passs" << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, both `pointer + integer` and `integer + pointer` operate pointer arithmetic and give a new pointer and thus the output is "normal".